# How to bind an event listener only once in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, events

I already know the Jquery solution

```
$('#myid').one('click', function(event) {
  ...
});
```

But now I'm finding the Pure JavaScript way because I'm not using Jquery

I have checked the **once option** but it is not supported by all browsers see the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Parameters)

Comment: @blex no it doesn't because the answers of that question talk about the difference between addEventListener and attachEvent/onclik method whereas I'm talking about executing either of them once

Comment: The once parameter is not supported by all browsers see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Parameters)

Answer (score 10):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

You can pass the third argument, an options object, with `{ once: true }`

At the bottom, you'll notice it doesn't work for IE :(

```js
const myElement = document.getElementById('my-element-id');

myElement.addEventListener('click', function namedListener() {
  // Remove the listener from the element the first time the listener is run:
  myElement.removeEventListener('click', namedListener);

  // ...do the rest of your stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the event listener function, you can then remove the event listener, like so:

```
document.getElementById("myid").addEventListener("click", handler);

// handler function
function handler(e) {
    // remove this handler
    e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);

    alert("This event will fire only once!");
}
```

Edit:  Although the above solution works, as mentioned in the comments, `arguments.callee` has been depreciated, and can throw errors when using `use strict;`, therefore an alternative solution would be like this:

```
// handler function
var eventHandler = function(e) {
  // remove this handler
  e.target.removeEventListener('click', eventHandler, false);

  alert("This event will fire only once!");
}

document.getElementById("myid").addEventListener("click", eventHandler);
```

Comment: The once parameter is not supported by all browsers see [docs] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Parameters)

Comment: Note cautions on use of [*arguments.callee*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee). Much better to use the function's name (especially since it has one due to being declared).

Comment: Hasn't `arguments.callee` been deprecated for over a decade?

Comment: Isn't it better to use e.currentTarget instead of e.target ?

Comment: no @Bruce, e.currentTarget will be null if e.type is scroll

Comment: ok, I was focused on my usage (click event)